# How to turn off PHP Imagick's readimage warnings

Tags: php, imagick

I am using PHP package Imagick. When I call method readimage I get this annoying warnings for some PDF's:

```
 **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
 **** The file was produced by:
 **** >>>>  <<<<
 **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
 **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
 **** specification.
```

This is whole code that I am using:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->setResolution(100, 100);
$img->readimage("scan-qr.pdf[0]");
$img->setImageFormat('gif');
$img->writeImage("scan-qr-$quality.gif");
$img->clear();
$img->destroy();
```

Any ideas how to turn off this warnings?